# Performance issues when rendering first frame of ThreeJS app

Tags: performance, three.js

I currently have a big impact on the performances of my ThreeJS app when I render the **very first frame**. It causes the Edge and IE 11 browsers to freeze for 5 seconds with a pop-up indicating "This window does not respond", which may scare my users.

Using the Performance profiler of Chrome, it seems the problem come from several ThreeJS functions you can clearly identify in the screenshot below.

- `WebGLUniforms.upload` : 425ms (50.7% frame rendering time)
- `WebGLProgram.constructor` : 327ms (38.9% frame rendering time)

[image]

How can I minimize the duration of the functions call ?

Can I create the program over multiple frames? Or upload the uniforms?

Does the number of materials on my 3D models impact these functions ?

I've tried to hide all the models in the scene and show them one at a time, it seems to prevent the freeze, but each model takes 500ms to show, which is not perfect for user experience. Maybe, it's the only way to go.

Thanks for your time

---

**EDIT** : The number of materials or their nature (WebGLStandardMaterial?) seems to affect the performances

Answer (score 2):

Put add a few objects to the scene per frame over time. Three.js inits WebGL resources on first use so if there's 100 objects on your scene all 100 objects get initialized the first time you call `renderer.render`.

So, just put N objects to the scene, call `renderer.render`, then next frame add N more to the scene, etc until all the objects have been added.

It's probably most important to do it by material and geometry. In other words if you have 10 different materials and 10 different geometries and you're rendering 100 different models (a model takes one material and one geometry), then you want to make sure the first N models you add don't use all the materials and all the models because those are the things that need to get initialized.

Post processing passes also need initialization so if you're using any of those maybe the first frame just init those, then start adding objects.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @gman. I've already tried your suggestion about adding my models one at a time, and call render between them. See the end of my question. I don't have any PostProcessing effect in the app. I will try to call `renderer.compile` to see the effects

Comment: Try adding them, not hiding them?

Comment: Adding the models one at a time, calling `renderer.render` between each of them had the same effect as hiding them all and showing them one at a time. Btw, i've not been able to call `renderer.compile` because ThreeJS can't find a vertex shader, I should have a look at it when I have time.

Comment: hiding / adding should be the same i think, the renderer will not set them up if they're part of the scene but invisible

Answer (score 0):

You can pre render your scene(s) during the first 1 second calling the **renderer.render(camera, scene)**.

First set auto clear to false

```
renderer.autoClear = false;
```

Your pre render does the first painting

```
const preRender = (time = 1000) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        const startTime = performance.now();

        function checkTime(currentTime) {
            if (currentTime - startTime >= time) {
                // pre render finished
                resolve();
            } else {
                requestAnimationFrame(checkTime);

                // so the first frames occur here!
                renderer.render(scene, camera);
                renderer.clear();
            }
        }

        requestAnimationFrame(checkTime);
    });
};
```

Then your instructions would look like this:

```
preRender().then(() => render());
```

Render is your loop, where you render your scene(s) normally.

```
const render = () => {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);

    // your custom logic
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

During pre render time you can show a **loading** and after that, the user experience is smooth.